# how to set path of maven manually without using archetype:generate?setting up path for maven java related

Tags: java, mongodb, maven

Using mvn archetype:generate we can set the path but manually how is it possible and what is the logic behind use of archetype:generate?

Comment: You should make your question more clear.

Comment: Thank you Nhu,but  I found the answer.I posted it below .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Apache Maven download and install for java**

go through the documentation first(https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi?Preferred=ftp://mirror.reverse.net/pub/apache/
unzip at some location

set path

```
go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System
go to advanced system settings->environment variables
in system variables->add to path
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin;D:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin



SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04

(in place of red fields change accordingly)
```

Install and check

```
go to D:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin
type mvn
then type mvn archetype:generate
```

before that if you are behind proxy follow the steps at *

```
now press enter to choose default option when asked choose a number or apply...
press enter again till asked groupId
give groupId:com.mongodb
artifactId:Nil1234
press enter several times till asked :Y::
type Y and press enter
```

should show BUILD Success

- proxy settings in maven
  go to apache-maven-3.3.9\conf folder and find settings.xml
  open it in any text editor
  go to the block of code that looks like below
   

    optional</id>
    true</active>
    http</protocol>
    proxyuser</username>
    proxypass</password>
    proxy.host.net</host>
    80</port>
    local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
  -->

Now uncomment the code from proxy.../proxy by cutting it and pasting it just after 
Now change according to your proxy settings
In my case it looks like the following

```
  <proxies>
  <proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>      
  <host>authproxy.serc.iisc.ernet.in</host>
  <port>3128</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
  <!-- proxy
 | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
 |

-->
</proxies>
```

Now try running mvn archetype:generate and it should run and download